# jquery setInterval or animate with easing

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval, easing

I've got a problem with setInterval and .animate(); during a project in jQuery/JavaScript.

I use the following code for start my interval:
`interval=setInterval(function(){initspin()},40);`

What it does with initspin():
`$('.device-carousel .spincontent').css('left','-'+(currimgnum-1)*imagewidth+'px');`

It moves the div container .spincontent every 40ms around 500px to the left side. It's necessary to do all the 500px steps, because the background-image of the .spincontent is a image-stripe of 22 images for a 3D spinner.

What I would like to have is, that after 50% of the .spincontent the ratio change from 40ms to 60ms for a lower/easing moving.

How can I realize this? Or is it better to switch to .animate()?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has clear easing functions that you can use with .animate().
It would be both cleaner, easier to understand, and smoother.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: The problem is, that I have to set all 40ms -500px, and not move from 0 to -500, from -500 to -1000, etc. Or is there a way to use .animate()?

Comment: jQuery has it's own interval which is used by animate(). If you use animate(), you don't have to care about the interval. If you truly need to have 40ms, you can modify jQuery.fx.interval (or something like that) or create your own interval without using jQuery.